# Deleting a record from a Bin File in C

Tags: c, file, bin

I'm trying to delete a record from a bin file.

I tried to make another pointer and make a temp file to write the data into it and then from the temp file write the data back to the original file..I suppose there is maybe an easier way. but the main question is what to change in update salary function.

here is what I did so far.

So the main goal of the program is if I enter extra money that is bigger than the threshold I should remove the record. any suggestions what do I need to change in update salary function?

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct employee
    {
        int  code;
        char  name[15];
        float  salary;
    } Employee;

    void create_bin(char *f, float* threshold);
    void updateSalary(char* filename, float threshold);
    void Display(char *fName);

    void main() {
        char filename[20] = "input.bin";
        float threshold;
        create_bin(filename,&threshold);
        Display(filename);
        updateSalary(filename, threshold);
        Display(filename);
        getch();
    }

    void create_bin(char *f,float* threshold){
        FILE *f_b;
        Employee emp1;
        int object=0,number,i=0;
        float amount;
        f_b = fopen(f, "wb+");
        if (!f_b) {
            printf("unable to open file");
        }
        printf("How many Employees?");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            printf("Eneter employee Code:");
            scanf("%d",&emp1.code);
            rewind(stdin);
            puts("Enter name");
            gets(emp1.name);
            printf("Eneter employee Salary:");
            scanf("%f",&emp1.salary);
            rewind(stdin);
            object += fwrite(&emp1, sizeof(Employee), 1, f_b);
        }
        printf("Ente threshold:");
        scanf("%.2f",&amount);
        *threshold = amount;
        printf("Total elements in file %d\n", object);
        fclose(f_b);
    }

    void updateSalary(char* filename, float threshold) 
    {
        float extra_money;
        int i = 1;
        Employee emp;
        FILE *f = fopen(filename,"rb+");
        FILE *f_temp = fopen("Final_file","wb+");
        if (!f)
        {
            printf("File not found!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if (!f_temp) {
            printf("File not found!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        fread(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f);
        while (!feof(f))
        {   
            printf("Enter how much money to add to #%d worker:",i++);
            rewind(stdin);
            scanf("%f",&extra_money);
                emp.salary+= extra_money;
                if (emp.salary <= threshold) {
                    fwrite(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f_temp);
                }
                fread(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f);
        }
        fread(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f_temp);
        while (!feof(f_temp)) {
            fwrite(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1,f);
            fread(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f_temp);
        }
        fclose(f_temp);
        fclose(f);
    }
    void Display(char *fName)
    {
        Employee emp;
        FILE *f = fopen(fName, "rb");
        if (f)
        {
            fread(&emp, sizeof(emp), 1, f);
            while (!feof(f))
            {
                printf("%9d %15s %8.2f\n", emp.code, emp.name, emp.salary);
                fread(&emp, sizeof(emp), 1, f);
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all **never** use floating point numbers for the financial calculations.

Comment: Secondly do not delete it from the file. Jest make it invalid or free. It will require a bit more logic in data structures.

Comment: P__J__ this is what I was required. the structure is given and I do have to delete from the bin file this is what I was asked for.

Comment: This is what I consider as the safer way: Read original file and write a new file. When done rename the original file to something like original filename + `".bak"`. Rename the new file to name of original file. Then remove the original file. With this concept, you always have at least one intact file if anything goes wrong. (The potentially needed double disk space, I would consider as invest into safety.) Btw. I learnt this from Turbo Pascal IDE some decades ago... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the main question is what to change in update salary function.

Follow Scheff's good advice: *Rename the new file to name of original file.* To do so, change

```
        fread(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f_temp);
        while (!feof(f_temp)) {
            fwrite(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1,f);
            fread(&emp, sizeof(Employee), 1, f_temp);
        }
        fclose(f_temp);
        fclose(f);
```

to

```
        fclose(f_temp);
        fclose(f);
        rename(filename, "Backup_file");    // optional, or maybe remove(filename);
        rename("Final_file", filename);
```

Besides that,

```
        scanf("%.2f",&amount);
```

has an invalid conversion specification; perhaps you meant

```
        scanf("%2f", &amount);
```